# DjangoRestFramework not validating required = True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am facing a very weird issue today.

Here is my serializer class.

```
 class Connectivity(serializers.Serializer):

    device_type = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
    device_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)

class Connections(serializers.Serializer):

    device_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
    connectivity = Connectivity(required = True, many = True)


class Topologyserializer(serializers.Serializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,required=True, \
                                  validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Topology.objects.all())])
    json = Connections(required=True,many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return validated_data
```

I am calling `Topologyserializer` from a Django view and I am passing a json like:

```
{

    "name":"tokpwol",
    "json": [

    ]
}
```

As per my experience with DRF since I have mentioned `required = True` in `json` field it should not accept the above json.

But I am able to create record.
Can anyone suggest me why it is not validating the json field and how it accepting empty list as json field?

I am using django rest framework 3.0.3

Comment: why are you defining the `create` method if all it does is returning the validated_data?

Comment: BTW, how are you creating the record? if you want to return a Topology object (instance) you need to instantiate one with `return Topology(**validated_data)` or create it with django's `return Topology.objects.create(**validated_data)`

Comment: @pynshia  I am using DRF  to validate the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRF does not clearly state what `required` stands for for lists.
In its code, it appears that validation passes as long as a value is supplied, even if that value is an empty list.

If you want to ensure the list is not empty, you'll need to validate its content manually. You would do that by adding the following method on your `TopologySerializer`:

```
def validate_json(self, value):
    if not value:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Connections list is empty")
    return value
```

I cannot test it right now, but it should work.